# Wordpress ajax not working in registration

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, ajax

guys. I've tried to build a wordpress simple registration form with ajax, but it doesn't work at all. Here is my code, a php and jQuery ajax. Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

FYI, (1) the 'alert' didn't work, (2) the data didn't entered into my custom table, (3) I added 'e.preventDefault()' and 'return false' in 'my-test-reg.js' but it doesn't avoid resubmsission form when I reload the browser.

```
// The .php function code

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );

// Load scripts
function load_scripts()
{
    // I called jquery.min.js and jquery validation from function.php, not from here

    wp_enqueue_script('test-reg', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-test-reg.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true ); 

    wp_localize_script( 'test-reg', 'myAjax', array(
        'myUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ) 
    );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_register', 'to_register' );
}

function to_register()
{
    $nonce = $_REQUEST['nonce'];

    if ( empty( $_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-nonce') )
    {
        die('Oopss...');
    } else {
        global $wpdb;

        $firstName = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['firstName)'] );
        $lastName  = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['lastName)'] );
        $email     = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );

        $custom_table = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_table";
        $the_email = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT `email` FROM $table_name" );

        if ( $the_email == $email )
        {
            $res['type'] = 'error';
            $res['show'] = '<span> The e-mail you entered already exists</span>';

            $res = json_encode($res);
            echo $res;

            die();
        } else {
            $entered = $wpdb->insert ($custom_table, 
                array(
                    'firstName' => $firstName, 
                    'lastName' => $lastName, 
                    'email' => $email
                ), 
                array(
                    '%s', 
                    '%s', 
                    '%s'
                ) 
            );
        }

        if ( $entered )
        {
            $res['type'] = 'success';
            $res['show'] = '<span> Hello, you\'re success! </span>';

            $res = json_encode($res);
            echo $res;

            die();
        }
    }
}

function reg_form()
{
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('nonce');

    $out = '<form id="test-register" method="post">';
    $out = '<div id="response"></div>';
    $out = '<input type="text" name="firstName" id="your-firstName" required>';
    $out .= '<input type="text" name="lastName" id="your-lastName" required>';
    $out .= '<input type="text" name="email" id="your-email" required>';
    $out .= '<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Go">
            <input type="hidden" id="my-nonce" value="'.$nonce.'">';
    $out = '</form>';

    return $out;
}


// Here is my code of 'my-test-reg.js'
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var formIsValid = $('#test-register');

    formIsValid.validate();

    $('#test-register').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the data
        var mydata = {
            action: 'add_to_register',
            firstName: $(this).find('#your-firstName').val();
            lastName: $(this).find('#your-lastName').val();
            email: $(this).find('#your-email').val();
        };

        // Call the ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: myAjax.myUrl,
            data: mydata,
            success: function ( response )
            {
                if ( response.type == 'success' )
                {
                    alert( 'Congrat, you are success!' ); // Doesn't work
                    $( '#response' ).html();  // Doesn't work
                } else {
                    alert( 'Not Success!' );  // Doesn't work
                    $( '#response' ).html();  // Doesn't work
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Hopefully anyone would help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Move this action ' add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_register', 'to_register' );' from load_scripts function().

```
// Load scripts
function load_scripts()
{
    // I called jquery.min.js and jquery validation from function.php, not from here

    wp_enqueue_script('test-reg', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-test-reg.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true ); 

    wp_localize_script( 'test-reg', 'myAjax', array(
        'myUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ) 
    );


}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_register', 'to_register' );
```

Replace reg_form() function with following:-

```
function reg_form()
{
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('nonce');

$out = '<form id="test-register" method="post">';
$out .= '<div id="response"></div>';
$out .= '<input type="text" name="firstName" id="your-firstName" required>';
$out .= '<input type="text" name="lastName" id="your-lastName" required>';
$out .= '<input type="text" name="email" id="your-email" required>';
$out .= '<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Go">
        <input type="hidden" id="my-nonce" value="'.$nonce.'">';
$out .= '</form>';

return $out;
}
```

You haven't concatenated the $out variable.

Comment: Ok, I did. But nothing happens as before.

Comment: Try to defined '$res = array()' in to_register() first then add type and show to $res.

Comment: Nothing happens. I try to make it simple by changing this  if ( empty( $_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-nonce')) { die('Oopss...') } else { echo "Horay"; }. By this checking, neither 'Oopss' and 'Horay' showed up. I think something wrong with the form, but I can't figure it.